# White screen when using Firebase in my Flutter APP. It works in debug mode

Tags: flutter, firebase

I have had the same issue with different Apps. I work in debug mode and everything seems working fine even firebase. since I am able to write database, authenticate, use cloud functions etc.. but once I build in this case for web then I hosted the website and t simply does not work. any idea would be really appreciate. Thank you

I've tried different options like adding the script from Firebase on my index.html.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" and [Build a minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)

Comment: That's in the website hosting logs? Can you run it locally in release mode?  What errors do you get?

Comment: Hi Thank you for your advice, I have fixed just changing my flutter channel from master to stable. Thank you !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.